# Proving the pointwise limit of a monotonically increasing sequence of Riemann integrable functions is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the following statement

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded set that has volume. Let $f : A \mapsto \mathbb{R}, f \ge 0$ be an unbounded function. Suppose $C_i$ is a sequence of compact sets with volume, $C_i \subset A$ with $C_i$ increasing to $A$. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable iff $f$ is Riemann integrable on each $C_i$ and $\lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{C_i} f$ exists.

My attempt. Let $M > 0$ be given.
Define
$$
f_M(x) = \min \{ f(x), M\}
$$
$$
f_i = f \chi_{C_i}
$$
Then $\{f_i\}$ is a sequence of non-negative functions such that $f_i \le f_{i+1}$ and $f_i \to f$ pointwise. Now, if $f$ is integrable on each $C_i$ and $\lim_{i\to \infty} \int_{C_i} f < \infty$, then the set of discontinuities of $f_M$ on $C_i$ has measure zero for all $i$. Let $x_0 \in \{ \text{discontinuities of} \ f_M \ \text{on $A$} \}$ be given. Since $C_i$ increases to $A$, there exists $N$ such that $f_M$ is discontinuous at $x_0$ on $C_N$. So $x_0 \in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \{ \text{discontinuities of} \ f_M \ \text{on $C_i$} \ \}$. Since $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \{ \text{discontinuities of} \ f_M \ \text{on $C_i$} \ \}$ has measure zero, the set of discontinuities of $f_M$ on $A$ has measure zero. Thus, $f_M$ is integrable. Since this is true for all $M > 0$, $f$ is integrable. Then by Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem,
$$
\lim_{i\to \infty} \int_{C_i} f = \lim_{i\to \infty} \int_A f_i = \int_A f
$$
Conversely, suppose $f$ is integrable. Since each $C_i$ is a compact subset of $A$ with volume, then $\{\text{discontinuities of} \ f_i \} \subset \partial C_i \cup \{ \text{discontinuities of} \ f \}$ has measure zero, so $f_i$ is integrable, i.e. $f$ is integrable on each $C_i$. Then by Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem,
$$
\int_A f=\lim_{i\to\infty} \int_A f_i = \lim_{i\to\infty} \int_{C_i} f
$$.

Is my proof mathematically correct? Is there a more direct way of proving the statement? Any comment would be appriciated.

Comment: You need to clarify the notion “Riemann integrable”. Does it mean integrable in the usual sense or in the improper sense.

For a function to be “Riemann integrable” in the usual sense, it must be bounded. In another word, an unbounded function is not Riemann integrable in the usual sense.

Comment: I see. In my case, I think the statement actually implies Riemann integrable in the improper sense.

Comment: In general, if $f_n \nearrow f$ pointwise and $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$, then it is possible that none of $f_n$  are discontinuous.  You can't assert that there is $M > N$ such that $f_M$ is discontinuous at $x_0$ just on these hypotheses.  You would need consider the specific construction $f_i = f \chi_{C_i}$.

Comment: Also for the improper (or extended) integral $\int_A f$ to exist you need  $\int_{C_i} f$ to be a bounded sequence.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what $f_{\chi_{C_i}}$ means?

Comment: It is just your definition with the indicator function notation, $f_i(x) = f(x)$ on $C_i$ and $0$ otherwise.  Is it possible you are missing something in the problem statement.

Comment: For example, with $n = 1$, the functions $f_j(x) = x^{-1}\mathbf{1}_{[1/j,1]}(x)$ are all integrable and $f_j(x) \to f(x) = x^{-1}$ on $(0,1]$, but $f$ is not integrable in any sense.

Comment: Indeed, I missed the statement that $\lim_{i\to \infty} \int_{C_i} f < \infty$. Also, I thought I defined $f_i$ the way you proposed. I've fixed that in the problem statment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reverse implication, suppose $D \subset A$ is any compact set with volume (i.e., rectifiable).  Since $D \subset \cup_{i=1}^\infty C_i=A$, there exists by compactness a set $C_m$ such that $D \subset C_m$.

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $C_m$ , it is Riemann integrable on $D$. (Here you would make the argument that the discontiuities of $f\chi_D$ must be a set of measure zero.)  Thus, since $f \geqslant 0$,

$$\int_D f \leqslant \int_{C_m} f \leqslant \lim_{i\to \infty}\int_{C_i} f < \infty,$$

and

$$\int_A f := \sup_{D \subset \mathcal{D}} \int _D f\leqslant  \lim_{i\to \infty}\int_{C_i} f,$$

where the supremum is taken over all compact rectifiable subsets of $A$.  This proves the existence of the improper integral of $f$ over $A$ -- **as it is usually defined.**

Comment: The forward implication proof is straightforward. Before going too far here you should confirm what your definition is for the improper Riemann integral of an unbounded function over a bounded open set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just to clarify, the discontinuities of $f \chi_D$ is a set of measure zero because it is a subset of the union of $\partial D$ and the discontinuities of $f \chi_{C_m}$, both of which have measure zero? Also, for the froward implication, is it possible to state that $\int_{C_i} f \le \int_A f < \infty$ to conclude $f$ is integrable on each $C_i$?

Comment: Yes - that statement about the discontinuities of $f \chi_D$ is correct.  Also by definition the boundary of $D$ must be of measure zero as well. So any discontinuity there does not matter.

Comment: The forward statement seems to me to be fairly trivial.  Each $C_i$ is itself a compact rectifiable subset of $A$ and $\int_{C_i} f \leqslant \sup_{D \subset \mathcal{D}}\int_D f = \int_A f$.  Again a little argument is needed to handle any potential discontinuity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You saved my day!